# Set speaker on Android 4+

Tags: android

It looks like it's a bug in Android 4+. 
I've searched in all the topics and didn't found a single answer that works.

The problem: I'm trying to make a phone call with a speaker on.

What I've tried to set the speaker on:

```
mAudioManager=(AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
mAudioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL);
mAudioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(true);
```

The code works perfect untill Android 4

But as for Android 4+ this does not work at all. The speaker is still off.

Any ideas?

P.s: I've included the permissions for this CALL_PHONE,MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS,READ_PHONE_STATE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. 
For all of you who are still searching for the answer. 
Well this is not a bug , but just a tricky thing . 
You need to use the PhoneStateListener

Using this guide : http://danielthat.blogspot.co.il/2013/06/android-make-phone-call-with-speaker-on.html